# Prevent closing tag on dynamically created input element?

Tags: javascript, html, input

After appending </input> element to the list item , and appending a child element to it, the browser generates a invalid </input> tag. How can I prevent this from happening? In the element inspector the created elements are there, but I can't see them or select their content.
I've put the entire code  here:
https://codepen.io/elenderg/pen/eYYJxqg

```js
var Matricula = "<strong>PAM5913</strong><br>";
var Velocidade = "N0250";
var Origem ="SBHT&emsp;";
var Destino = "<strong>SBBE</strong><br>";
var Hora = "<strong>1600</strong>"
var Tipo = "E195M"
var Transponder = "6721";
var Nível = "F370";
var Rota = "DCT";

function CriaStrip(){
var Ul = document.getElementById('ul');
var Li = document.createElement('li');

Li.setAttribute("class", "cinza li");

var Input = document.createElement('input');

Input.setAttribute('name', 'painel');
Input.setAttribute("type","radio");
Input.setAttribute("id","input1");

var Label = document.createElement('label')
Label.htmlFor = 'input1';

var Div1 = document.createElement('div');

Div1.setAttribute("class", "lado-a-lado");
Div1.innerHTML = Matricula + Origem + Destino + Hora + Tipo;


var Div2 = document.createElement('div');

Div2.setAttribute("class", "dados");
Div2.innerHTML = Transponder + Nível + Rota + "<br><br>" + Velocidade;



Ul.appendChild(Li);
Li.appendChild(Input);
Input.appendChild(Label);
Label.appendChild(Div1);
Div1.appendChild(Div2);


}
```

```css
.painel{
    border: 4px solid rgb(0,0,255) ;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: black;
}
.cinza{
    background-color: gray;
    border-bottom: 1px solid silver;;
    
}
.ul{
    margin:0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;  
}
.li{
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
    height: 70px;
}
.li label{
    bottom: 1px;
    left: 1px;
    right: 1px;
    top: 1px;
    display: block;    
    position: absolute;
}
input[type="radio"]{
  display: none;
}
.lado-a-lado{
    display: -webkit-box;    
}
.dados{
    padding-left: 3px;
}
.ul input:checked + label {
    border-right: 8px solid white;
  }
```

```html
<div class="painel" onclick="CriaStrip()"> 
        <ul class="ul" id="ul">
            <li class="cinza li" id="li">  
                    Click to create new items           
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: just don't append to `<input/>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to change how you're appending the label. You should append it to Li instead of Input

```
Ul.appendChild(Li);
Li.appendChild(Input);
Li.appendChild(Label); // From Input to Li
Label.appendChild(Div1);
Div1.appendChild(Div2);
```